# Fragment should be static such that they can be re-instantiated by the system

Tags: android, android-fragments, payment-gateway

I am using Payumoney payment gateway in my app, everything was good until i decided to generate signed apk. It shows this error:
Error:Error: Fragments should be static such that they can be re-instantiated by the system, and anonymous classes are not static [ValidFragment].
It is generating normal apk though.
Here is my code:

```
    public class OldPaymentActivity  extends AppCompatActivity implements MagicRetryFragment.ActivityCallback{
    Bundle bundle;
    String url;
    boolean cancelTransaction = false;
    PayuConfig payuConfig;
    private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = null;
    private String UTF = "UTF-8";
    private  boolean viewPortWide = false;
    private WebView mWebView;
    private Boolean smsPermission;
    private int storeOneClickHash;
    private String merchantHash;
    MagicRetryFragment magicRetryFragment;

    String txnId = null;
    public OldPaymentActivity(){

    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        /**
         * when the device runing out of memory we dont want the user to restart the payment. rather we close it and redirect them to previous activity.
         */
        if(savedInstanceState!=null){
            super.onCreate(null);
            finish();//call activity u want to as activity is being destroyed it is restarted
        }else {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        }
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_payments);
        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        //     WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
        //region Replace the whole code by the commented code if you are NOT using custombrowser
        // Replace the whole code by the commented code if you are NOT using custombrowser.

        bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        payuConfig = bundle.getParcelable(PayuConstants.PAYU_CONFIG);
        storeOneClickHash = bundle.getInt(PayuConstants.STORE_ONE_CLICK_HASH);
        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

        url = payuConfig.getEnvironment() == PayuConstants.PRODUCTION_ENV?  PayuConstants.PRODUCTION_PAYMENT_URL : PayuConstants.TEST_PAYMENT_URL ;

        String [] list =  payuConfig.getData().split("&");

        String merchantKey = null;
        for (String item : list) {
            String[] items = item.split("=");
            if(items.length >= 2) {
                String id = items[0];
                switch (id) {
                    case "txnid":
                        txnId = items[1];
                        break;
                    case "key":
                        merchantKey = items[1];
                        break;
                    case "pg":
                        if (items[1].contentEquals("NB")) {
                            viewPortWide = true;
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        try {
            Class.forName("com.payu.custombrowser.Bank");
            final Bank bank = new Bank() {
                @Override
                public void registerBroadcast(BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver, IntentFilter filter) {
                    mReceiver = broadcastReceiver;
                    registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, filter);
                }

                @Override
                public void unregisterBroadcast(BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver) {
                    if(mReceiver != null){
                        unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
                        mReceiver = null;
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onHelpUnavailable() {
                    findViewById(R.id.parent).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    findViewById(R.id.trans_overlay).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onBankError() {
                    findViewById(R.id.parent).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    findViewById(R.id.trans_overlay).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onHelpAvailable() {
                    findViewById(R.id.parent).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onBackPressed(AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog){
                    Toast.makeText(OldPaymentActivity.this, "payment activity onBackPressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onBackApproved(){
                    Toast.makeText(OldPaymentActivity.this,"payment activity onBackApproved",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }

                @Override
                public void onBackCancelled(){
                    Toast.makeText(OldPaymentActivity.this,"payment activity onBackCancelled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            };
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(Bank.WEBVIEW, R.id.webview);
            args.putInt(Bank.TRANS_LAYOUT, R.id.trans_overlay);
            args.putInt(Bank.MAIN_LAYOUT, R.id.r_layout);
            args.putBoolean(Bank.VIEWPORTWIDE, viewPortWide);
            args.putBoolean(Bank.AUTO_SELECT_OTP, false);
            args.putBoolean(Bank.AUTO_APPROVE, true);
            args.putBoolean(Bank.BACK_BUTTON, true);
            args.putString(Bank.TXN_ID, txnId == null ? String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) : txnId);
            args.putString(Bank.MERCHANT_KEY, merchantKey);

            smsPermission = getIntent().getBooleanExtra(PayuConstants.SMS_PERMISSION, true);//default true
            args.putBoolean(Bank.MERCHANT_SMS_PERMISSION, smsPermission);

            PayUSdkDetails payUSdkDetails = new PayUSdkDetails();
            args.putString(Bank.SDK_DETAILS, payUSdkDetails.getSdkVersionName());
            // should cb send the merchant hash back to app?
            args.putInt(Bank.STORE_ONE_CLICK_HASH, storeOneClickHash);
            if(getIntent().getExtras().containsKey("showCustom")) {
                args.putBoolean(Bank.SHOW_CUSTOMROWSER, getIntent().getBooleanExtra("showCustom", false));
            }
            args.putBoolean(Bank.SHOW_CUSTOMROWSER, true);
            bank.setArguments(args);
            findViewById(R.id.parent).bringToFront();
            try {
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.cb_face_out).add(R.id.parent, bank).commit();
            }catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                finish();
            }
            initMagicRetry();

            mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new PayUWebChromeClient(bank));
            mWebView.setWebViewClient(new PayUWebViewClient(bank, magicRetryFragment,merchantKey));
            //mWebView is the WebView Object
            magicRetryFragment.setWebView(mWebView);
            // MR Integration - initMRSettingsFromSharedPreference
            magicRetryFragment.initMRSettingsFromSharedPreference(this);

            mWebView.postUrl(url, payuConfig.getData().getBytes());
           // (new PayuUtils()).deviceAnalytics(OldPaymentActivity.this, Bank.Version, "data", txnId); //oqMs
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            mWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
            mWebView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
            mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
            // Setting view port for NB
            if(viewPortWide){
                mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(viewPortWide);
            }
            // Hiding the overlay
            View transOverlay = findViewById(R.id.trans_overlay);
            transOverlay.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new Object() {
                @JavascriptInterface
                public void onSuccess() {
                    onSuccess("");
                }

                @JavascriptInterface
                public void onSuccess(final String result) {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Intent intent = new Intent();
                            intent.putExtra("result", result);
                            if(storeOneClickHash == PayuConstants.STORE_ONE_CLICK_HASH_SERVER && null != merchantHash){
                                intent.putExtra(PayuConstants.MERCHANT_HASH, merchantHash);
                            }
                            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
                            finish();
                        }
//                }
                    });
                }

                @JavascriptInterface
                public void onFailure() {
                    onFailure("");
                }

                @JavascriptInterface
                public void onFailure(final String result) {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Intent intent = new Intent();
                            intent.putExtra("result", result);
                            setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, intent);
                            finish();
                        }
                    });
                }

                @JavascriptInterface
                public void onMerchantHashReceived(final String result) {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            switch (storeOneClickHash){
                                case PayuConstants.STORE_ONE_CLICK_HASH_MOBILE:
                                    try {
                                        JSONObject hashObject = new JSONObject(result);
                                        new PayuUtils().storeInSharedPreferences(OldPaymentActivity.this, hashObject.getString(PayuConstants.CARD_TOKEN), hashObject.getString(PayuConstants.MERCHANT_HASH));
                                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();

                                    }
                                    break;
                                case PayuConstants.STORE_ONE_CLICK_HASH_SERVER:
                                    merchantHash = result;
                                    break;
                                case PayuConstants.STORE_ONE_CLICK_HASH_NONE:
                                    break;

                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }, "PayU");
            mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() );
            mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
            mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
            mWebView.postUrl(url, payuConfig.getData().getBytes());
        }

        /*mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        // url = payuConfig.getEnvironment() == PayuConstants.PRODUCTION_ENV?  PayuConstants.PRODUCTION_PAYMENT_URL : PayuConstants.MOBILE_TEST_PAYMENT_URL ;
        mWebView.postUrl(url, EncodingUtils.getBytes(payuConfig.getData(), "base64"));*/
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_payments, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        //invalidate the DialogFragment to avoid stupid memory leak
        if (magicRetryFragment != null) {
            magicRetryFragment = null;
        }
    }

    private void initMagicRetry() {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        magicRetryFragment = new MagicRetryFragment();
        Bundle newInformationBundle = new Bundle();
        newInformationBundle.putString(MagicRetryFragment.KEY_TXNID, txnId);
        magicRetryFragment.setArguments(newInformationBundle);

        Map<String, String> urlList = new HashMap<String, String>();
        urlList.put(url, payuConfig.getData());
        magicRetryFragment.setUrlListWithPostData(urlList);

        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.magic_retry_container, magicRetryFragment, "magicRetry").commit();
        // magicRetryFragment = (MagicRetryFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentBy(R.id.magicretry_fragment);

        toggleFragmentVisibility(Util.HIDE_FRAGMENT);

        magicRetryFragment.isWhiteListingEnabled(true);
    }


    public void toggleFragmentVisibility(int flag){
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        if (!isFinishing()) {
            if (flag == Util.SHOW_FRAGMENT) {
                // Show fragment
                ft.show(magicRetryFragment).commitAllowingStateLoss();
            } else if (flag == Util.HIDE_FRAGMENT) {
                // Hide fragment
                ft.hide(magicRetryFragment).commitAllowingStateLoss();
                // ft.hide(magicRetryFragment);

            }
        }

    }



    @Override
    public void showMagicRetry() {
        toggleFragmentVisibility(Util.SHOW_FRAGMENT);
    }

    @Override
    public void hideMagicRetry() {
        toggleFragmentVisibility(Util.HIDE_FRAGMENT);
    }
}
```

Comment: link the third party sdk link

Comment: Sorry i din't get what you said! can you please elaborate!

Comment: I was asking to update your question to have link the third party sdk you included. Anyways I found the same problem reported on github [sdk](https://github.com/payu-intrepos/Android-SDK/issues/33)

Comment: i tried that solution, it din't work